# Vuetify Mobile Drawer: Square Corners?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I'm using the Vuetify mobile drawer component and would like it to have square corners rather than the rounded corners that seem to be a Material default for all Vuetify components.  The Vuetify card component has a "tile" property that allows you to square the corners, but the drawer component does not have this and nothing in the documentation discusses how to interact with the Material API.  I did try using the "rounded" property / border-radius, but this seems to be independent of that and it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this -- it has to do with the way the background is filled.  Setting

> ```
> .v-navigation-drawer__content {
>   background-color: { anything }
> }
> ```

seems to resolve the issue.  Still not quite sure what is being done behind the scenes to make the background have rounded corners.